# Clikable Hyperlink with SAS ODS EXCEL

Tags: excel, hyperlink, sas, ods

I got a problem with Hyperlink generated by SAS ODS EXCEl.
I'm using SAS9.4TM3 and EXCEL 2013.

I coded this

```
data lst_tie;
NUM_TIE = '2900004227803';
output;
NUM_TIE = '2900004233852';
output;
run;
data lst_tie(drop=HL);
set lst_tie;
format HL2 $500.;
HL = "http://tier-kh.cm-cic.fr/tie6_tiers/default.aspx?trt=tiesyn&banque=02297&caisse=38848&tiers="||NUM_TIE;
HL2 = '=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("'||HL||'";"'||NUM_TIE||'")';
run;

ods excel file = "$GRPFPU/test_tiesyn.xlsx"
    options (absolute_column_width="3cm,20cm,20cm");
proc report data=lst_tie
;
column  NUM_TIE   
        HL2;
define num_tie / "Numero" style(column)={ width=100%};
define HL2  / "Tiers" style(column)={tagattr='wraptext:no' width=100%};
quit; 
ods excel close;
```

The URL seems well encoded :

```
=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("http://tier-kh.cm-cic.fr/tie6_tiers/default.aspx?trt=tiesyn&banque=02297&caisse=38848&tiers=2900004227803";"2900004227803")
```

without carriage return (CR).

But, on opening the XLSX file there is a CR characters just after *LIEN_HYPERTEXTE* (HYPERLINK in English)

[XLSX Preview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6fSi.png)

But if I delete the CR so the hyperlink is OK.

[XLSX OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZkbT.png)

I tried several option as WIDTH_COLUMS, Wrap Option , but no way.

Thanks

Comment: Try using single quotes around the value of `HL`.

Comment: Since you are using an older version of SAS you will need to use the work around mentioned in this thread instead of the easier solution. added in SAS 9.4M4. https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/Lines-Wrapping-in-ODS-Excel/td-p/154925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a clickable hyperlink I add a format
``

```
data lst_tie;
    NUM_TIE = '2900004227803';
    output;
    NUM_TIE = '2900004233852';
    output;
run;

data lst_tie;
    set lst_tie;
    format HL2 $500.;
    HL = "http://tier-kh.cm-cic.fr/tie6_tiers/default.aspx?trt=tiesyn&banque=02297&caisse=38848&tiers="||NUM_TIE;
run;

data one;
    set lst_tie;
    retain fmtname '$urltie';
    rename NUM_TIE=start;
    label =  HL;
run;

proc format cntlin=one;
run;

ods excel file = "$GRPFPU/test_tiesyn.xlsx"
    options (absolute_column_width="3cm,20cm,20cm" flow="tables");

proc report data=lst_tie
;
    column  NUM_TIE   
    ;
    define num_tie / "Numero" style(column)={TAGATTR='format:0' width=1.5in url=$urltie. color=cx0000FF textdecoration=underline /*tagattr='wraptext:no' width=100%*/
    };
quit;

ods excel close;
```

``

Answer (score 1):

ODS EXCEL is trying to make your printout pretty by inserting physical line breaks into long lines. Apparently it doesn't notice that your value is a formula instead of plain text.

Starting with SAS 9.4M4 you can add `flow="tables"` to the ODS statement. See this [SAS Blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2017/02/20/tips-for-using-the-ods-excel-destination/)

```
ods excel file = "$GRPFPU/test_tiesyn.xlsx"
    options (absolute_column_width="3cm,20cm,20cm"
             flow="tables"
            )
;
```

For older versions of SAS, like yours, try making the column wider so it doesn't try to wrap it.  Try adding `width=1000%` instead of `width=100%` to the column with the links.

```
define HL2  / "Tiers" style(column)={tagattr='wraptext:no' width=1000%};
```

Comment: Thx Tom. It's better with *flow="tables"*  . But link are not active

Comment: Does just setting the value of a cell to something that looks like a formula actually make it a formula? You might need to make other changes to how you are trying to do this.